# How to read a value using QSetting if the value contains comma character

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

In my QT project I am reading values from .ini file using QSettings. If the value contains comma character QSettings is not able to read it. How should I read such values?

Comment: Comma character is treated as list separator by `QSettings`. Try to use `qDebug() << settings.value("key");` to see what it loads from your file. If it is a string list, you can convert it to string using `join(",")`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Yes, it is loading as QStringList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comma character is treated as list separator by `QSettings`. INI values with commas are parsed as string lists. You can convert a string list back to original string as follows:

```
QVariant value = settings.value("key");
QString string;
if (value.type() == QVariant::StringList) {
  string = value.toStringList().join(",");    
} else {
  string = value.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply create a ini file with qsettings and a comma in configuration string. Characters being control chars for ini-files will be escaped by `%` percent sign.

Comment: I think OP is talking about INI files not generated by Qt.