# QSettings: How to read array from INI file

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, ini, qsettings

I wanna read comma separated data form INI file. I've already read here:

- [QSettings::IniFormat values with "," returned as QStringList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557727/qsettingsiniformat-values-with-returned-as-qstringlist)
- [How to read a value using QSetting if the value contains comma character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052930/how-to-read-a-value-using-qsetting-if-the-value-contains-comma-character)

...that commas are treated as separators and QSettings value function will return QStringList.

However, my data in INI file looks like this:

```
norm-factor=<<eof
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
eof
```

I don't need a whole matrix. All rows joined up together are fair enough for me. But can QSettings handle such structure?

Should I read this using:

```
QStringList norms = ini->value("norm-factor", QStringList()).toStringList();
```

Or do I have to parse it in another way?

Comment: Have you tried it? Why not?

Comment: Can you please supply a complete example so that we can run and modify it? It sounds like you didn't try to open it the way you suggest. Try it.

Comment: It is not standard ini format (for Qt). Possibly, you can't read it with `QSettings`.

Comment: I can't try it right now  ... I'll try it as soon as I'll be on pc with compiler

Comment: What you're showing is not an `.ini` file. Someone gave it an `.ini` extension, but it's a custom format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line breaks are a problem since INI files use line breaks for their own syntax.
Qt seems to not support your type of line continuation (`<<eol ... eol`).

```
QSettings s("./inifile", QSettings::IniFormat);
qDebug() << s.value("norm-factor");
```

yields

```
QVariant(QString, "<<eof")
```

The `<<eol` expression might be invalid INI in itself. ([Wikipedia on INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file))

I suggest you parse the file manually.

Comment: Please consider Accepting/Check-Marking the answer and upvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

Ronny Brendel's answer is correct ...i am only adding code that solves above problem ...it creates temporary INI file with corrected arrays:

```
/**
 * @param src source INI file
 * @param dst destination (fixed) INI file
 */
void fixINI(const QString &src, const QString &dst) const {

  // Opens source and destination files
  QFile fsrc(src);
  QFile fdst(dst);
  if (!fsrc.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QString msg("Cannot open '" + src + "'' file.");
    throw new Exception(NULL, msg, this, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
  }
  if (!fdst.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QString msg("Cannot open '" + dst + "'' file.");
    throw new Exception(NULL, msg, this, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
  }

  // Stream
  QTextStream in(&fsrc);
  QTextStream out(&fdst);

  bool arrayMode = false;
  QString cache;
  while (!in.atEnd()) {

    // Read current line
    QString line = in.readLine();

    // Enables array mode
    // NOTE: Clear cache and store 'key=' to it, without '<<eof' text
    if (arrayMode == false && line.contains("<<eof")) {
      arrayMode = true;
      cache = line.remove("<<eof").trimmed();
      continue;
    }

    // Disables array mode
    // NOTE: Flush cache into output and remove last ',' separator
    if (arrayMode == true && line.trimmed().compare("eof") == 0) {
      arrayMode = false;
      out << cache.left(cache.length() - 1) << "\n";
      continue;
    }

    // Store line into cache or copy it to output
    if (arrayMode) {
      cache += line.trimmed() + ",";
    } else {
      out << line << "\n";
    }
  }
  fsrc.close();
  fdst.close();
}
```